# Java regex - spaces

Tags: java, regex

I can't seem to figure out the regex I need. This is what I want to achieve:

{ANY CHAR} + @javax.persistence.Column(name = "{ANY 30 CHARS}") + {ANY CHAR}

Also I think where I'm struggling with: the "name = " might be "name=" or "name ="

What would the regex be to search like this in Java?

Comment: use `\s*` for `0-n` spaces.

Comment: `\\bname\\s*=\\s*`

Comment: Aha, tnx. How would the full regex look like then? Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full regex should look like,

```
.*@javax\\.persistence\\.Column\\(name\\s*=\\s*\".{30}\"\\).*
```

Comment: `.{30}` expects exactly 30 chars , for 1 to 30, use `{1,30}`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Here you should find all the info you need for a specific number of characters / whitespaces etc.and general regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

From your description:

```
 ".@javax\\.persistence\\.Column\\(name ?= ?\".{30}\"\\)."
```

Though this is probably not what you want, as it matches exactly 30 chars - seems unusual to me.